# Dynamically sort HTML table with row categories

Tags: javascript, html

There are any number of nice JS libraries to make HTML tables dynamically resortable on the client, but I haven't been able to find one that handles rows that are categorized.  Here's a small example of the kind of table I mean:

```
╔═══╦═════════╦═══════╦══════════════╗
║   ║  Name▾  ║  Zip  ║     Pet      ║
╠═══╬═════════╬═══════╬══════════════╣
║   ║ Alice   ║ 14124 ║ Squirrel     ║
║ A ║ Alfred  ║ 24601 ║ Meerkat      ║
║   ║ Anupam  ║ 91532 ║ Gila monster ║
╠═══╬═════════╬═══════╬══════════════╣
║   ║ Bernice ║ 03413 ║ Rock         ║
║ B ║ Boris   ║ 32610 ║ Fish         ║
║   ║ Betty   ║ 71011 ║ Elephant     ║
╚═══╩═════════╩═══════╩══════════════╝
```

Has anyone written a table sorter that will automatically split up the categorization column when the table is sorted on the Zip or Pet columns (so now it looks like this:

```
╔═══╦═════════╦═══════╦══════════════╗
║   ║  Name   ║  Zip▾ ║     Pet      ║
╠═══╬═════════╬═══════╬══════════════╣
║ B ║ Bernice ║ 03413 ║ Rock         ║
║ A ║ Alice   ║ 14124 ║ Squirrel     ║
║ B ║ Boris   ║ 22310 ║ Fish         ║
║ A ║ Alfred  ║ 24601 ║ Meerkat      ║
║ B ║ Betty   ║ 71011 ║ Elephant     ║
║ A ║ Anupam  ║ 91032 ║ Gila monster ║
╚═══╩═════════╩═══════╩══════════════╝
```

) and re-merge it again when the table is sorted on Name?  Failing that, how about a table sorter that knows how to sort *only within the categories*, leaving the order of categories alone?  (This is acceptable for the real table that I want to sort, though obviously not for this toy example.)

I will also be happy to take Better Ideas for this situation, if anyone's got one.

Comment: It seems that the algorithm would be to: 1) remove separators (if any), 2) sort by desired column using any sort code, 3) check if sort column wants separators and if so, scan row by row to add separator in desired location.

Comment: I can change the way the HTML is generated if it makes things significantly easier client-side, but right now there are no separator rows (there may, however, be "this is the first row in this category" class labels - the style hasn't quite been finalized yet) and the "category" column has a lot of `<td rowspan="X">`, which makes munging it enough of a pain that I'm hoping someone has already written it for me.

Comment: This might be overkill for the task, but I know [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) handles dynamic grouping. However, it's using a different grouping layout. I'm pretty sure you could intercept the sorting action to remove grouping when you want.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I tried to make a code for your problem.
Its not the best way to do it, but it seems it worked hehe.
Let me know if it is good for you, and if so, if you are fine to implement it the way you want.

I will try to improve it and transform it to a jQuery plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/chambs/TRnP7

```
var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');

var data = [
    {name: 'Alice', zip: '14124', pet: 'Squirrel'},
    {name: 'Alfred', zip: '24601', pet: 'Meerkat'},
    {name: 'Anupam', zip: '91532', pet: 'Gila monster'},
    {name: 'Bernice', zip: '03413', pet: 'Rock'},
    {name: 'Boris', zip: '32610', pet: 'Fish'},
    {name: 'Betty', zip: '71011', pet: 'Elephant'}
];

var lastType = '';

function getHeader() {
    var row = this[0],
        header = [];
    for(var k in row) {
        header.push(k);
    }
    return header;
}

function sortBy(criteria) {
    lastType = criteria;
    var c = criteria || 'name';
    return this.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[c] > b[c];
    });
}

function render(tbl, data) {
    tbl.empty();
    var buffer = "<tr><th class='letter'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>",
        header = getHeader.call(data);
    for(var i=0; i < header.length; i++) {
        buffer += "<th class='sort' data-type='"+header[i]+"'>"+header[i]+"</th>";
    }
    buffer += "</tr>";
    tbl.append(buffer);
    buffer = "";

    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var l = data[i].name.substr(0, 1);
        buffer += "<tr><td class='"+l+"'>" + l + "</td>";
        for(var j=0; j < header.length; j++) {
            var k = header[j];
            buffer += "<td>" + data[i][k] + "</td>";
        }
        buffer += "</tr>";
        tbl.append(buffer);
        buffer = "";
    }

    if(lastType === 'name') {
        merge(tbl);
    }

}

function merge(tbl) {
    for(var i=0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        var l = letters[i];
        var td = $('.' + l, tbl);
        if(td.length > 1) {
            td.eq(0).attr('rowspan', td.length);
            $('.' + l + ':gt(0)', tbl).remove();
        }
    }
}

sortBy.call(data, 'name');
render($('#tbl'), data);
$(document).on('click', '.sort', function(ev) {
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    sortBy.call(data, type);
    render($('#tbl'), data);
});
```