# Django Python - Javascript Dynamic Table sorting rows

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, django

I have never done any javascript but I saw that this is what I am looking for to display a dynamic table one of my html template.
I have read that there should be something using JQuery but not much more.
So I am looking exactly for an example of dynamic table able to sort rows following which column is selected, written in javascript, displayed in an HTML template, using:
 - as columns: the fields of a MySQL table (see example below).
 - as rows: the entries contained in the same table
And all of this has to use Django (I don't know if the javascript file either has to be separated from the HTML template or has to be in the HTML template)

Example MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE PDB(
    id_PDB_chain CHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_PDB CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    chaine VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    header VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    sequence_Proteine TEXT NOT NULL,
    start_seq INT NOT NULL,
    taille_Proteine INT NOT NULL,
    resolution_PDB FLOAT NOT NULL,
    meth_Res VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (meth_Res)
    REFERENCES methodes_res(meth_Res)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Corresponding class in the "models.py" file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Pdb(models.Model):
    id_pdb_chain = models.CharField(db_column='id_PDB_chain', primary_key=True, max_length=5)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_pdb = models.CharField(db_column='id_PDB', max_length=4)  # Field name made lowercase.
    chaine = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sequence_proteine = models.TextField(db_column='sequence_Proteine')  # Field name made lowercase.
    start_seq = models.IntegerField()
    taille_proteine = models.IntegerField(db_column='taille_Proteine')  # Field name made lowercase.
    resolution_pdb = models.FloatField(db_column='resolution_PDB')  # Field name made lowercase.
    meth_res = models.ForeignKey('MethodesRes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='meth_Res')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id_pdb

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PDB'
```

In case you need any other informations just ask in comments and I will edit this post with the informations.

Comment: You can use python to select the data and dynamically build the table you seek. Javascript or Jquery is not needed for this. Look into Python loops and how to implement them into Django Templates. You could essentially do the same thing in PHP without javascript as well, but since this is Django you will want to use python.

Comment: A python For loop should work nicely for this

Comment: Yes to generate rows of my table I used a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me and it was really simple in fact:

first you have to download jquery and jquery.tablesorter. Here is the official website where you can download everything and where everything is explained : http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Then, as I work with Django my HTML templates are in a "myapp/templates" directory and my CSS and Javascript files are in a "myapp/static/myapp/" directory.

Here is the template I used:

```
{% load static %}

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/style.css' %}" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp/jquery-3.2.0.min.js' %}">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp/jquery.tablesorter.min.js' %}">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
        $("#pdbtable").tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
</script>
</head>

{% if protdb %}
    <table id="pdbtable" align="center" border="3" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>PDB Id</th>
        <th>Chain</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Resol.</th>
        <th>Method Res.</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for i in protdb %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/pdbapp/{{ i.id_pdb_chain }}">{{ i.id_pdb }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ i.chaine }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.header }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.taille_proteine }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.resolution_pdb }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.meth_res }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
{% else %}
    <p>No PDBs are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And here is my corresponding view:

```
def pdbinfo(request):

    protdb = Pdb.objects.order_by('id_pdb_chain')\
    [:len(Pdb.objects.order_by('id_pdb_chain'))]

    context = {
        'protdb': protdb
    }

    return render(request, 'pdbapp/pdbinfo.html', context)
```

As you maybe know, since you are using Django, your template has to receive all informations from a view in views.py and the table of your database (in my case I use MySQL) have to be filled with entries.

This code is working, take some inspiration from it.

One other content that helped me and that gives more details is a youtube video, check the link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wAWfPVXlME&t=334s

I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py create a view under whatever name you'd like. Create a list and set it to whatever data you want from your specific model. now go to your template. With that list populated by your specific data you have chosen from the database, use an If statement to check to see if there is anything residing in that list. If there is data there then you can use a For loop like so:

```
{% for model_name in list_name %}
    model_name.model_data etc # Mark it up with relevant html table code, though divs are more preferred
```

You can mark up the data as needed to display a table, though divs would be more compliant and nicer than tables. This is just a basic example. On the Else statement if no data exists in the list ahead of time, you can simply output that no data exists. Take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/ 
They walk you through building a polling app, where it is relevant to you is the index.html template they build pulling the question data from the database and displaying an unordered list of the questions on the home page as links to vote on. Simply follow this tutorial and look at how they implement the models.py and views.py along with the template and then change the markup from am unordered list to whatever suits your needs.

Comment: But this way it's not dynamic, and you are not using javascript.
I have read this tutorial, and there nothing in it about what I am trying to do. I need to use javascript.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: How is it not dynamic? Im primarily a web developer first and foremost. I use PHP, HTML, CSS, and Javascript everyday. This is dynamically creating a table or the instance of the tutorial a list to display on the page. Please define what you specifically need in order for it to be "dynamic" The DB can be updated and python can still output the new data to the page with only a few lines of code. I promise you, javascript is not needed. Trust me.

Comment: With simple markup from html you can output the specific data to the headers of the table, the rows, and columns as well. Each time python loops through, it will build more and more of your table. Once it reaches the end of the loop, you can simply have the markup close the table off and viola, you have a dynamically generated table with the data from your database

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear, I am a very beginner into those things. By dynamic I mean that for example, if I clic on the header of one column in the table, it will sort rows following this column. I would like to have this option for each column in the table and each column header will correspond to one field in one table of my database.
And I think the library JQuery in javascript is the best way to handle this, but I don't know how to integrate it in my website. If you have a javscript example of sorting table like this one written in javascript that would be perfect.

Comment: If you also know maybe a website providing a tool generating automatically the javascript code to do this, I am also interested. 
What is an HTML markup ?

Comment: The way I read it was, you wanted to create a table dynamically from the data in the database, not sort the data based on header clicks from a table. My bad. I will dig around and see what I can find for you. Ajax may be another route for this as well.

Comment: One possible solution. Is this what you are looking for? Sorting the table via the headers, so you could do things like alphabetical, numerical, ascending, descending, etc? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751899/dynamically-sort-html-table-with-row-categories

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry for replying late. I finally found something that worked for me in javascript. I write an answer ASAP about it.